# Resizing disk space

Tags: 12.04, wubi, resize

I'm using Wubi 12.04. When I installed, the disk size was 18 GB. Now I'm almost running out space. But I have enough space in Windows drive in which I installed Wubi.

I tried to increase the size of Ubuntu from this link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk

But it gives the message:

```
wubi-resize.sh: The new size (5 GB) isn't sufficient to hold your
wubi-resize.sh: existing install (18 GB) plus a freespace buffer
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to make the disk smaller (according to the posted error log, 5Gb). Try to make it bigger than 18Gb!

Comment: Seems it works.......Thanksss.....but to know how much time it needs to complete it. Have any idea!!!!



wubi-resize.sh:  A new virtual disk of 20 GB will be created. Continue? (Y/N)
Y
wubi-resize.sh: Creating new virtual disk (new.disk)...

Comment: Not too much in this case. :)

Comment: Need your immediate help pls...
I missed this step. as I now checked it and found out that in ubuntu the disk size didnt increase but from windows drive the disk size had been decreased...
**6. You're done! Reboot into windows, rename the file \ubuntu\disks\root.disk to \ubuntu\disks\OLDroot.disk and rename the file \ubuntu\disks\new.disk to \ubuntu\disks\root.disk. Then reboot back into Ubuntu -- only delete the OLDroot.disk if you are sure it worked.**